# HttpContext.User is null when i call protected web Api ASP-NET Core (AzureAD) from Frontend Angular 9

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-api, httpcontext, angular9

I have a issue with HttpContext.User in my BackEnd App (web api Asp-Net-Core 3.1) when the protected web api are called from angular application, the value of HttpContext.User is NULL. In my angular application i can authenticate with Azure AD so when i make the http request i put inside the header: "Bearer + access_token" as requested, necessary to call my protected web Api invoking Microsoft graph Api. If i Run only Backend application ad use Chrome i have no problem because the value HttpContext.User isn't null and i can invoke Microsoft Graph Api. I use MSAL library(in both applications) for login in Azure AD an interceptor component in angular to fill up the header.

this is Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .AllowCredentials());
        });
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityPlatformAuthentication(Configuration)
       .AddMsal(Configuration, new string[] { Constants.Constants.ScopeUserRead     })
       .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
        services.AddGraphService(Configuration);
        services.AddControllers();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();


    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

}

this is the HomeController.cs that i call in angular:

```
 //[Authorize]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    //[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        readonly ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition;
        readonly WebOptions webOptions;
        //private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition,
                              IOptions<WebOptions> webOptionValue)
        {
            this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
            this.webOptions = webOptionValue.Value;
            //this._logger = logger;
            //ILogger<HomeController> logger
        }


        [HttpGet]
        [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { Constants.Constants.ScopeUserRead})]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
        {
            var x = HttpContext.User;
            var y = User.Identity;
            var z = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            // Initialize the GraphServiceClient. 
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient(new[] { Constants.Constants.ScopeUserRead });

            var me = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

            return Ok("ciao");

        }

        private GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient(string[] scopes)
        {
            return GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(async () =>
            {
                string result = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUserAsync(scopes);
                return result;
            }, webOptions.GraphApiUrl);
        }
```

this is custom.interceptor.ts:

```
    const accessTokenRequest = {
    scopes: ["user.read"]
}

@Injectable()

export class CustomInterceptor extends MsalInterceptor {

    constructor(private msalService: MsalService, private broadcast: BroadcastService) {
        super(msalService, broadcast);
    }

    public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return from(this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(token => {
            const JWT = `Bearer ${token.accessToken}`;
            return req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: JWT,
                },
            });
        })).pipe(mergeMap(r => next.handle(r)));
    }

}
```

This is app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'MSAL Angular - Sample App';
  isIframe = false;
  loggedIn = false;
  // private authService: AuthService;
  private router: Router;

  constructor(private broadcastService: BroadcastService, private authService: MsalService, private httpClient: HttpClient, private injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isIframe = window !== window.parent && !window.opener;

    this.checkAccount();

    this.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:loginSuccess', () => {
      this.checkAccount();
    });

    this.authService.handleRedirectCallback((authError, response) => {
      if (authError) {
        console.error('Redirect Error: ', authError.errorMessage);
        return;
      }

      console.log('Redirect Success: ', response.accessToken);
    });

    this.authService.setLogger(new Logger((logLevel, message, piiEnabled) => {
      console.log('MSAL Logging: ', message);
    }, {
      correlationId: CryptoUtils.createNewGuid(),
      piiLoggingEnabled: false
    }));
  }

  checkAccount() {
    this.loggedIn = !!this.authService.getAccount();
  }

  login() {
    const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;

    if (isIE) {
      this.authService.loginRedirect();
    } else {
      this.authService.loginPopup();
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  callApi() {
    this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:64449/home").toPromise().then((x) =>
    console.log(x)
  );
  }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Looks like you are not saving the token, so it is not being available to the controller after it passed the authorization pipeline. Can you put a debug point in the profile method & check if the control is coming upto there.

Comment: @PrateekKumarDalbehera I've already tried. When  the callApi method starts it arrives to te controller (Profile method) but when call the Graph Api, the frontend returns a issue with a Microsoft Identity platform's parameter: "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'accountIdentifier')" and "Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUserFromCacheAsync(IConfidentialClientApplication application, string accountIdentifier, IEnumerable<string> scopes, string loginHint, string tenant)". As if the Httpcontext is not set

Comment: So, you are saying that you are trying get access token for a given user from Azure AD in "string result = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUserAsync(scopes);". But, it's throwing error - right? Are you missing something in the azure configuration? Here, what does 'accountIdentifier' signifies? need to identify what is this

Comment: One more query - why are requesting access token from the CSharp code, you should have already got that in Angular. You just need to pass that as Bearer which looks like you are doing correctly. Can you please explain more about your scenario.